# ElementNotInteractableException in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, automated-tests

I'm trying to run a test (which is working just fine in selenium IDE) through python, but I get this exception when trying to click on one of the element (which is definitely visible and interactable).
The only difference between this element to other elements is the fact that its in a list.
I've been trying to get to it using xpath, css selector, etc... nothing worked.
Any ideas why it happens and how to solve it?

Comment: Please post the exception that you get, as well as the related code.

Comment: Why not just access the element in the list? el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('pathToElement'). Then el[0].click().